# sklearn module not found in anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, anaconda

I've been trying to import sklearn but it says that the module is not found.

my python, numpy, scipy and scikit versions are as follows as show in the conda list:

```
numpy                     1.14.3           py36h9fa60d3_1

python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0

scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0

scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0
```

the error while trying to import sklearn is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f2461ba6e1e9> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.family import model

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.family'
```

I tried using

```
conda update scikit-learn

conda install scikit-learn
```

but I get the following results

> All requested packages already installed.

how do I import sklearn then?

Comment: 1) There is no module `sklearn.family` 2) you probably have multiple environments, and you are trying to work from Jupyter in one where the module is indeed not installed; try `conda env list` from the command line (or `conda info --envs`) to see your existing environments

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Although there is not skleran module, `from sklearn import ...` works well in PyCharm:

```
from sklearn.utils import resample
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing

```
conda install -c anaconda pip
pip install sklearn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there's no sklearn.family module. Have you tried importing other modules?
Say,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Have you tried opening the Anaconda Navigator->Environments and searching for scikit-learn? What does it say?

Comment: it has a checkbox which is checked and it says "set of python modules for machine learning and data mining".
version 0.19.1

Comment: mmm.... have you been working with virtual environments? Maybe you're working on an environment without sklearn

Comment: how to check that if I'm working on virtual environments? and even if that was the case then importing any module shouldn't have been possible since all the modules are in the same directory but importing numpy, scipy, seaborn everything works except sklearn!! So I'm very confused

Comment: As mentioned by desertnaut, you can try `conda env list` in Anaconda prompt and see if you have more than one environment. You'll want to go to your base environment, for which you can use `deactivate`

Comment: # conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3... looks like there is only one environment that is the base environment